# Currently an intern and another intern position has opened up with higher pay

Tags: internship, internal-transfer

I hope this is not a duplicate due to my 'different' situation as an intern:

I am classified as an intern where I am currently working, but I have been here for over a year now. I am basically a part-timer but still with the intern title i.e. there is no plan for me to quit working. I am in my last year of school, and, if given the opportunity, will probably transition to full-time.

Recently I got an email from my school that stated a different intern position has recently opened up at the company I work for with higher pay. The position is for an Application Development/Business Analysis internship which is basically what I am doing right now. Better yet, it's in the same location as where I am working right now.

I don't know whether I should apply for the position (send in a resume to someone already in the same company), email/ask the recruiter about the position and explain my situation, or contact my manager and explain the situation. I have not had a raise, and I do not expect one as an intern, but I also don't want to let an opportunity like this go to waste.

Comment: Can you come up with a single reason as to why you would not apply to the higher paying position?  ( Hint:  Just apply!! )

Comment: As @MisterSortofPositive said, just apply, and then you can add more details (if necessary) when the process continues.

Comment: I think it's more of that I don't know how to approach the situation

Comment: @A.B. Sure you do.  Just like you would if you were interested in a higher paying non intern type job.  Apply, interview, and if an acceptable offer is obtained turn in your notice to your existing work place, and start your new gig after....

Comment: @MisterSortofPositive should I consider it as a separate position even though it is for the same company?

Comment: @MisterSortofPositive I think the fact that it's at the same company is an important fact here. You don't want the boss to find out from someone else in the company that you applied for the other job. It also may not be worth applying for the job if you can achieve the same result by asking for a raise.

Comment: Yep @DavidK I missed that.  Need to look at the internal policies on how that will work.  Definitely company specific.

Comment: You say the new position "is basically what I am doing right now", but is it *exactly* what you're doing now or is it similar but clearly not the same? If it's different you can apply, but the best way depends on company policy. If it's the same, applying for a position you're already in just to get higher pay doesn't make sense; it makes more sense to ask for a raise, but [this says you shouldn't do that either](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/92027/how-to-negotiate-a-raise-as-an-intern) (although you've been there a while...). When does your school year end? December? May/June?

Comment: Since the company has to search for another intern anyway this is just inconvenient for them. So I would agree to not applying for the position but talk to your manager about it (and a possible raise). However if that turns out negative you could talk to the other department head and consider transferring.

Answer (score 1):

You explained you have been working for the company for over a year as an intern and that you are in your last year of school with prospects of getting permanently hired. Applying for *another* internship position with the same company makes no sense under these circumstances and would forfeit the purpose of an internship. Your goal is to realized higher payment. Based on the advertised positions and the experience you gained with your employer, it should be possible for you to negotiate a raise.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should apply! Positions that are open to external applicants are generally open to internal applicants as well and as long as you meet the requirements, definitely apply!

Answer (score 0):

Why shouldn't you apply?

There are many sayings that apply to this but the first that comes to mind is that it's an automatic NO if you don't ask.

Another is "nothing ventured, nothing gained"

But seriously, your first concern must be for yourself and the downsides are few, if any but there's a good upside in that there's higher pay.

Another benefit is networking. You'll expose yourself to more people in te company and that can't hurt either.

Go for it!

Comment: Because he loses his seniority and won't get the full time position after a year.